# export LD_LIBRARY error

Tags: c++, cygwin, environment-variables

I have a profile file where I set my cygwin environment variable.

I have first set my TTCN3_DIR:

```
export TTCN3_DIR=${HOME}/Documents/TITAN_files/TITAN
```

And when I type $TTCN3_DIR on the terminal here is the result :

```
-bash: /cygdrive/c/Users/qi11091/Documents/TITAN_files/TITAN/: Is a directory
```

But the problem is when I want to add a library to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH like this :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${TTCN3_DIR}/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

I have this result when I type $LD_LIBRARY_PATH :

```
-bash: /cygdrive/c/Users/qi11091/Documents/TITAN_files/TITAN/lib:: No such file or directory
```

I don't know if I did not set the variable properly or if is another error

Answer (score 0):

because there is :: at the end of the path

do the following:

```
unset TTCN3_DIR
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH

export TTCN3_DIR=/cygdrive/c/Users/qi11091/Documents/TITAN_files/TITAN
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$TTCN3_DIR/lib
```

hopefully that will help you

Comment: So I remove the :${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} ?
Because I want to add ${TTCN3_DIR}/lib to the existing LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 0):

To print an environment variable, use `echo $TTCN3_DIR` instead of just `$TTCN3_DIR`.
Your problem is, i think, because you use braces on the second line.
Try :
`export TTCN3_DIR=$HOME/Documents/TITAN_files/TITAN`
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$TTCN3_DIR/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: I did that ut I still have the : problem when I type echo :

    $ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    /cygdrive/c/Users/qi11091/Documents/TITAN_files/TITAN/lib: